# How to send email of a GSuite/Google Workspace alias domain externally (e.g. via Ubuntu)

Tags: email, smtp, ubuntu-18.04, google-workspace, ubuntu-server

#### Scenario

I have **`domain.com`** on GSuite. Then I have **`aliasdomain.com`** (which is set as an alias domain for that in GSuite.) And I have a GSuite User *`admin`* (which is both *`admin@domain.com`* and *`admin@aliasdomain.com`* just like I want them to be.  Emails sent to either are received via gmail's **`admin@domain.com`** account, all good.

Now I have an **Ubuntu 18.04 Server** from which I would like to send mail as *`admin@aliasdomain.com`*. I have learned that I need to use Google SMTP to accomplish that.

#### What I've tried

I've also learned that [nullmailer](https://github.com/bruceg/nullmailer) is light and since I only wish to send a mail very occasionally, it is perfect, so I'd like to use that **preferably**, but *Postfix* or *sendmail* can also be an option, if that doesn't work.

Unfortunately I have very limited understanding of anything related to mail transfer agents, etc. But I've tried my best to search for a resource or a guide for this particular scenario, but most of them are quite advanced to me, and they assume the reader to be very well-versed.

#### What I need

How do I set up sending mail using the above scenario? I am hoping someone kind enough to guide me in this regard.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, after some trial and error, I finally got it all working.  Here's a step-by-step tutorial (sort of) if anyone is interested:

1. G SUITE/WORKSPACE:

   1. Log in to *`admin@domain.com`*'s gmail and enable  **Send mail as** (refer to its [section of Step 3 here](https://support.google.com/a/answer/7502379?hl=en), under *Send messages from your alias address*
   2. Log in to **`domain.com`**'s [Google Admin Console](https://admin.google.com/) > **Apps** > <s>**GSuite**</s> **Google Workspace** > **GMail** > **End user access** > Enable **Allow per-user outbound gateways**
2. UBUNTU 18.04 SERVER:

   1. Install **nullmailer**  `sudo apt-get install nullmailer` (then accept all default values for now, we're changing them below)
   2. `cd /etc/nullmailer`
   3. `sudo nano defaultdomain` and replace all text with `aliasdomain.com`
   4. `sudo nano adminaddr` and replace all text with `admin@aliasdomain.com`
   5. `sudo nano remotes` and replace all text with `smtp.gmail.com smtp --port=465 --auth-login --user=admin@domain.com --pass=YOURPASSWORDFORadmin@domain.comGMAILACCOUNT --ssl` (***Read important security note below before doing this step!***)
   6. `sudo systemctl enable nullmailer`
   7. `sudo systemctl start nullmailer`
3. NULLMAILER:

   1. Nullmailer should now be ready
   2. Test it: `printf "Subject: Nullmailer test\nFrom:admin@aliasdomain.com\nTo:example@hotmail.com\n\nTest from Nullmailer" | sendmail -v example@hotmail.com`
   3. Check *example@hotmail.com* Inbox for email from *admin@aliasdomain.com* (you might have to look in Spam folder and mark it as Safe for future OR see new **SPF record** addition below.)

#### IMPORTANT SECURITY NOTE

Before attempting Step 2.5, You must **either** enable two-factor authorization for **`admin@domain.com`** and use [App Passwords](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en) **OR** enable [Less secure apps](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en). It's your decision ultimately.

#### SPF DNS RECORD

You may have to include `domain.com` and `aliasdomain.com` in the an [SPF TXT RECORD](https://support.google.com/a/answer/10685031) to.